# using module.exports - ES6 import

Tags: javascript, module, node-modules

Still (relatively) new to modules - trying to use npm packages using ES6 import, running as both a browser app and a node app...

ES6 Modules seem to work fine for custom code:

```
exporting module:
export function foo() {}

importing module:
import * as functions from  './functions.js'
functions.foo ()
```

I can execute the above as both a browser app and node app.

But for npm packages (e.g. lodash), - importing modules created with module.exports using the same ES6 syntax:

- works fine for node apps
- fails when implemented as a browser app, which has been configured with type = module (to support other custom modules in my app):

```
<script type="module">
    import { app } from './js/modules-app.js'
    app()
</script>
```

```
exporting module (from lodash):
module.exports = function_name

importing module:
import apply from '...lodash/_apply.js'
```

I get the following error:
Uncaught SyntaxError SyntaxError: The requested module '../../node_modules/lodash/_apply.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

If I change the export statement in lodash to the following, it works fine, but obviously that's not a viable solution:

```
exporting module (from lodash):
export function_name () {}
```

So, I basically understand that ES6 modules and CommonJS are separate protocols, but for the purpose of taking a course on JS, I'd like to access npm modules using ES6 syntax while running my apps in both a browser and node.

Simply put - is there a way to import functions that have been exported using module.exports into an ES6 module?

The best article I can find on this topic is [here](https://adamcoster.com/blog/commonjs-and-esm-importexport-compatibility-examples) - TBH, it's really frustrating to deal with what seems to be very incompatible protocols.

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es

Comment: @Konrad - aha! the simple answer! Do all npm packages have this alternative, or is it hit or miss as to whether a pkg has been updated for ES6? I'm guessing more and more pkg's will offer an ES6-enabled solution...Thx so much!

Comment: @IMTanuki If you want to use ES modules for everything, then in the browser you can only use packages that support ES modules. For all others, people usually use a bundler that supports whatever format the package is distributed as.